# How to group a list of grouped lists?

Tags: c#, list, linq, linq-group

I need a grouped list of grouped lists; I have a bunch of articles that I need to group by year, and group by month within each year. It will look something like this on the page:

#### 2015

### February

Article 1 Title

Article 2 Title

### January

Article 3 Title

---

#### 2014

### December

Article 4 title

---

I know how to get one grouped list, such as

```
var yearList = articles.GroupBy(x => x.Year);
```

But how can I group a list of grouped lists?

This is my article class:

```
public class Article
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String DateDisplay { get; set; }
    public String MoreLink { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I want a grouped list by Year, that contains grouped lists by month

Comment: Can you post the relevant classes ?

Comment: Edited to include my article class

Comment: `var yearList = articles.GroupBy(x => new {x.Year, x.Month}).GroupBy(x=> x.FirstOrDefault()?.Year);`

Comment: @Bart That would group by months, grouping each month by year, not the other way around.

Comment: @Bart And last I checked, C# 6.0 wasn't out yet.

Comment: Null check aside, two consecutive GroupBy calls is a fine solution.

Comment: @moarboilerplate Except that the groups end up being inside out.

Comment: @Bart that's fantastic, the one problem is that the month headings are showing up as { Month = 2 }, any idea how to fix this? It's being displayed as <%#Eval("Key")%>

Comment: @user3784238 not sure what you mean, month is an int.

Comment: I mean it's displaying as <h1> { Month = 1 } </h1>, rather than <h1> 1 </h1>

Comment: You have to use SelectMany to flatten and get rid of the keys from the IGrouping. (item => item)

Comment: @user3784238 you need to iterate over 2 groups now instead of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing you have an `Article` class with `Year` and `Month` properties, this will do:

```
var perYearAndPerMonth = articles.GroupBy(a => a.Year)
                                 .Select(yearGroup => new
                                 {
                                     Year = yearGroup.Key,
                                     PerMonth = yearGroup.GroupBy(a => a.Month)
                                                         .Select(monthGroup => new
                                                         {
                                                             Month = monthGroup.Key,
                                                             Articles = monthGroup.ToList()
                                                         })
                                 });
```

Converting the month groupings to an anonymous type is of course not necessary, but makes it more clear what you actually get in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Each item in your sequence is a group, to transform each item in your sequence into something else, use `Select`.  Within that `Select` you need to transform each group into a sequence of groups.  To actually transform the one group into a sequence of groups, use `GroupBy`.

Comment: I know I need to use GroupBy. I don't know how to use GroupBy on a grouped list though.

Comment: @user3784238 And I told you exactly how; you call `Select` on what you currently have.

Comment: Since `IGrouping`, the return type of `GroupBy`, implements `IEnumerable`  use `GroupBy` again.